# iPhone: Date conversion issues

Tags: iphone

I need to check an event date, which should be between Current date and 60 days from now. The below code is used, but it is NOT working correctly. Please note, i'm getting event string like this - "2012-04-14T16:50:02Z"  from my server.

```
// current date
double currDateInMilliSecs = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] * 1000;    
NSLog(@"currDateInMilliSecs: %f", currDateInMilliSecs);

// sixty days
double sixtydaysvalue = 60.0 * 24.0 * 3600.0 * 1000.0;
NSLog(@"sixtydaysvalue: %f", sixtydaysvalue);
// add current date + sixt days
double sixtyDaysMilliSecsFromCurrDate = currDateInMilliSecs + sixtydaysvalue;
NSLog(@"sixtyDaysMilliSecsFromCurrDate: %f", sixtyDaysMilliSecsFromCurrDate);

// check does the event date between current date + 60 days
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
//[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

// [eventDict objectForKey:@"begin_at"] gives date string like this "2012-04-14T16:50:02Z"  for ex.
NSDate *eventdate = [df dateFromString:[eventDict objectForKey:@"begin_at"]];

NSTimeInterval nowSinceEventDate = [eventdate timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog(@"nowSinceEventDate: %f", nowSinceEventDate);
double eventDateInMilliSecs = nowSinceEventDate * 1000;
NSLog(@"eventDateInMilliSecs: %f", eventDateInMilliSecs);

// this is not working as expected    
if ( eventDateInMilliSecs<sixtyDaysMilliSecsFromCurrDate && eventDateInMilliSecs>currDateInMilliSecs )
{


}
else
{
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: If you need to dispaly milli second along with time like 3:43:12:23 folly my answer or @vinay's answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: Issue comparing a date between current date and sixty days from current date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228816/iphone-issue-comparing-a-date-between-current-date-and-sixty-days-from-current)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2012-04-14T16:50:02Z";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
NSDate *eventDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSTimeInterval nowSinceEventDate = [eventDate timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog(@"interval = %f", nowSinceEventDate);
```

**UPDATE:**

```
NSString *dateString = @"2012-05-21T16:50:02Z";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
NSDate *eventDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setDay:60];

NSDate *minDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *maxDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:minDate options:0];

NSLog(@"eventDate interval = %f", [eventDate timeIntervalSince1970]);
NSLog(@"minDate interval = %f", [minDate timeIntervalSince1970]);
NSLog(@"maxDate interval = %f", [maxDate timeIntervalSince1970]);

BOOL isBetween = (([eventDate compare:minDate] == NSOrderedDescending) && ([eventDate compare:maxDate] == NSOrderedAscending));
NSLog(@"isBetween = %d", isBetween);
```

Comment: Actually i did that already, it is working. My problem is new now. I want to compare "2012-04-14T16:50:02Z" date should be between current date and plus 60 days. So i added the logic like getting current date in milliseconds and then adding 60 days milliseconds plus the current date(milliseconds) and compare that with the dateString="2012-04-14T16:50:02Z" millisecs. But, it is not comparing properly as i need. Because, current date is 356530435017.459961, plus 60 days is 361714435017.459961, but the dateString="2012-04-14T16:50:02Z" millisecs is 1336559400000.000000.Any help?

Answer (score 1):

try this

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss SSS"];

Comment: this is correct if need to dispaly milli second along with time like 3:43:12:23

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS"];
// [eventDict objectForKey:@"begin_at"] gives "2012-04-14T16:50:02Z"
NSDate *eventdate = [df dateFromString:[eventDict objectForKey:@"begin_at"]];
```

**[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];**

***SSS*** for milli seconds