# iPhone: Issue comparing a date between current date and sixty days from current date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to check an event date, which should be between Current date and 60 days from now. The below code is used, but it is NOT working correctly. Please note, i'm getting event string like this - "2012-04-14T16:50:02Z" from my server.

```
    // current date
double currDateInMilliSecs = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] * 1000;    
NSLog(@"currDateInMilliSecs: %f", currDateInMilliSecs);

// sixty days
double sixtydaysvalue = 60.0 * 24.0 * 3600.0 * 1000.0;
NSLog(@"sixtydaysvalue: %f", sixtydaysvalue);
// add current date + sixt days
double sixtyDaysMilliSecsFromCurrDate = currDateInMilliSecs + sixtydaysvalue;
NSLog(@"sixtyDaysMilliSecsFromCurrDate: %f", sixtyDaysMilliSecsFromCurrDate);

// check does the event date between current date + 60 days
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
//[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

// [eventDict objectForKey:@"begin_at"] gives date string like this "2012-04-14T16:50:02Z"  for ex.
NSDate *eventdate = [df dateFromString:[eventDict objectForKey:@"begin_at"]];

NSTimeInterval nowSinceEventDate = [eventdate timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog(@"nowSinceEventDate: %f", nowSinceEventDate);
double eventDateInMilliSecs = nowSinceEventDate * 1000;
NSLog(@"eventDateInMilliSecs: %f", eventDateInMilliSecs);

// this is not working as expected    
if ( eventDateInMilliSecs<sixtyDaysMilliSecsFromCurrDate && eventDateInMilliSecs>currDateInMilliSecs )
{


}
else
{
}
```

Comment: Not working in what way?

Comment: use compare function for NSDate.

Comment: It is not comparing as expected because milli seconds coming for example like this, Current DateInMilliSecs: 356532141059.288025 ; SixtyDaysMilliSecsFromCurrDate: 361716141059.288025 ; An eventDateInMilliSecs: 1336172400000.000000 which is actually for 2012-05-04 19:00:00 +0000. So, it is actually coming under today's date from 60 days, but my condition is not working as expected.

Comment: See my answer below... you should try to work with things within the Cocoa framework rather than as in Java, it will be easier... but your actual issue is with your reference dates. Your _now_ date is based on the *Cocoa Reference Date*, which 2001-01-01T00:00:00Z. Your event date is based on the *Unix Reference Date*, which is why your comparisons don't work. Don't convert to seconds (and if you do, there's absolutely *no* reason to convert to milliseconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to solve this as if it were Java, which it's not. Instead, try using things from the Cocoa Touch frameworks. Since your calculations are rather simple, you can do them with dates, but more complex things can pretty easily be done using NSCalendar and NSDateComponents.

A simple solution to your problem (here we assume `eventdate` is the date you created using your formatter):

```
NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
NSDate* sixtyDaysFromNow = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60 * 60 * 24 * 60)];
if( [eventDate earlierDate:now] == now && [eventDate laterDate:sixtyDaysFromNow] == sixtyDaysFromNow ) {
  // the event date is within scope
} else {
  // the event date is outside stop
}
```

Comment: @Getsy What do you mean by "updating"?

Answer (score 0):

use my function for comparing date its working on my project

i hope its help you

```
-(BOOL)date:(NSDate*)date isBetweenDate:(NSDate*)beginDate andDate:(NSDate*)endingDate

{

    if ([date compare:beginDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
        return NO;

    if ([date compare:endingDate] == NSOrderedDescending) 
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```